# How to point Superset to different DB on basis of client request

Tags: multi-tenant, apache-superset

I want to use superset where depending on which client request is coming from (clientA.domain.com vs clientB.domain.com), my request goes to the correct customer DB.

So far, all the documentation for Superset has not helped me in this regard. I think there should be a way.

BTW, I am aware of the option where we can put all customer's data in the same DB, with client_id column which helps distinguish one customer's data from another. However, if I am dealing with an enterprises, this is not an option (they won't let their data coexist with another customer's). So while I'm looking for a single Superset application process, I want it to point to different DB.